# Swift pod dependency Firebase, pod spec lint error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I had some problem when I create a cocoaPod by swift,my swift pod dependency firebase. Everything is ok when I develop my pod, but there is one error when I pod spec lint.
Here is the error:

```
 - WARN  | source: Git SSH URLs will NOT work for people behind firewalls configured to only allow HTTP, therefore HTTPS is preferred.
    - WARN  | url: There was a problem validating the URL https://xxxxxxxxxxx.
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `MyPod` depends upon `FirebaseCore` and `FirebaseCrashlytics`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

Here is my pod spec:

```
  s.static_framework = true
  s.subspec 'Common' do |ss|
      ss.source_files = 'Source/Common/**/*.swift'
  end
   s.subspec 'MyPodFirebase' do |ss|
       ss.source_files = 'Source/Firebase/**/*.swift'
       ss.dependency 'FirebaseCore'
       ss.dependency 'FirebaseAnalytics'
       ss.dependency 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
       ss.dependency 'MyPod/Common'
   end
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why are you defining your pod as static library?

Comment: What does "there is one error when I pod spec lint" mean?

Comment: @ElTomato hI, when I finish my private pod, I.want to push my pod, so I excuting the order "pod spec lint --verbose --allow-warnings --use-libraries --skip-import-validation"

Comment: @CloudBalancing Hi, you mean maybe I should delete 's.static_framework = true', let me have a try